# How to find all supported python, reStructuredText fieldnames?

Tags: python, restructuredtext

I'm trying to learn more than the common `:param myparam: Some description` documentation style common in many python modules, but haven't been able to identify a full list of supported fieldnames.  From examples, I've gathered `param`, `raises`, `returns`.

```
def my_method(self, someval):
    """Returns one plus the given value
    :param someval: an integer on which to operate
    :whatelseisthere:
    """
    return someval + 1
```

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html

Comment: Have a look at the section on that page [Field Lists](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#field-lists), the referenced [docutils field lists](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#field-lists), the Sphinx extension for [field lists](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/field-lists.html), and [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete list of field names can be found [here:](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html?highlight=domains#info-field-lists)

- **param, parameter, arg, argument, key, keyword:** Description of a parameter.
- **type:** Type of a parameter. Creates a link if possible.
- **raises, raise, except, exception:** That (and when) a specific exception is raised.
- **var, ivar, cvar:** Description of a variable.
- **vartype:** Type of a variable. Creates a link if possible.
- **returns, return:** Description of the return value.
- **rtype:** Return type. Creates a link if possible.