# How to document returning tuples in python for Pycharm with docstring

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, docstring

I have seen this question asked all over the internet, but with no answers that seem to work.

```
def testing_return_documentation(one, two):
    """
    tests documentation of arguments and returns
    :param one: testing
    :param two: another test

    :return: a thing
    """
    return one
```

Looks like this in Pycharm when you hover over the function:
[image]

But how do you document returning a tuple?

```
def testing_return_documentation(one, two):
    """
    tests documentation of arguments and returns
    :param one: testing
    :param two: another test
    :return: how do you make good things happen here?
    """
    return one, two
```

Comment: Found something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090037/documenting-tuple-return-type-in-a-function-docstring-for-pycharm-type-hinting

Comment: I had seen this earlier.  Unfortunately rtype does not work (shows nothing in the popup.)  The best I could do is: :returns: (str, str): Tuple of two strings, which is OK, but not a great answer.  I'll let this stay open for a few more days and see if anyone else has another suggestion

Comment: What version of python are you working with? Python implemented [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in 3.5. Pre 3.5 you have to do it a little different. Looks like you're using post 3.5 given your image. I don't have PyCharm in front of me ATM, and I'll try figuring something out later, but I'd start by essentially doing what your image shows `) -> tuple[int, Foo]`, see the documentation and search `tuple`. That should update the doc. For pre 3.5 I'm guessing something like `rtype: tuple[int, Foo]`

Comment: I am using Python 3.9.7 and PyCharm Professional 2021.2.4.  Return type would be nice, but I am really just trying to properly document the name and what it means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3.5 Python added [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). Before Python 3.5 existed, there was an open conversation around how to type hint, and it was done in comments. PyCharm supports type hinting in either. I'd recommend doing it the python way for a couple reasons, but it's up to you.

```py
"""These should work"""
from Typing import Tuple

class Foo:
    pass

def foo(a: int, b: float, c: Foo) -> Tuple[int, float, Foo]:
    return a, b, c

def bar(a, b, c) -> Tuple[int, float, Foo]:
    return a, b, c

def that(a, b, c):
    """
    :rtype: Tuple[int, float, Foo]
    """
    return a, b, c

def thing(a, b, c):
    """
    :rtype: (int, float, Foo)
    """
    return a, b, c
```

```py
"""This should fail because Tuple is not imported, but no warning"""
def that(a, b, c):
    """ 
    :rtype: Tuple[int, float, Foo]
    """
    return a, b, c

"""
This only partially works because 'Foo' isn't in scope. 
This can easily happen if someone refactored the name of 'Foo', 
but the comments wouldn't be updated.
"""
def thing(a, b, c):
    """
    :rtype: (int, float, Foo)
    """
    return a, b, c

def documentation_nightmare(a, b, c):
   """ ​
   There are no checks, and everything seems fine, but the documentation is all wrong and hard to maintain. 
   :param a: A
   :type a: float
   :param b: B
   :type b: Bar
   :param c: C
   :type c: int
   ​:rtype: Tuple[int, float, Foo]
   ​"""
   ​return a, b, c
```

The main pro of the Python way is.. your code will start to give you type hints and show warnings if you have the wrong types hooked up. If your whole code base is typed then you can run checks to make sure everything is hooked up right. Some people like this, some people don't.

Note, I have done `documentation_nightmare` before and I hated it. Now I do it with full real typing, and it saves me more time than it costs me, but many people dislike it.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411025/how-to-find-all-supported-python-restructuredtext-fieldnames) SO post:

The complete list of field name can be found [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html?highlight=domains#info-field-lists)

- **param, parameter, arg, argument, key, keyword**: Description of a parameter.
- **type**: Type of a parameter. Creates a link if possible.
- **raises, raise, except, exception**: That (and when) a specific exception is raised.
- **var, ivar, cvar**: Description of a variable.
- **vartype** : Type of a variable. Creates a link if possible.
- **returns, return**: Description of the return value.
- **rtype**: Return type. Creates a link if possible.
- **meta**: Add metadata to description of the python object. The metadata will not be shown on output document. For example, :meta private: indicates the python object is private member. It is used in sphinx.ext.autodoc for filtering members.

Comment: So how do you give an explanation of what the return variables represent? In the parameters section of the function's documentation, you can explain what they represent.

Comment: @jordanthompson To my understanding `:param foo: description` / `:type foo: type_info` -> `:return: description` / `:rtype: type_info`. So if you're trying to explain return info, that would go in `:return: description`. If you look above in your image, it says `a thing`. That's where you would explain something. That's the point of that keyword. If you're asking how I personally do it, I do it much less than I used to, but there's a large philosophy around that, and really depends on specifics related to you.

Comment: There are two books `Clean Code` or `Clean Architecture` (not all of which I agree with) that talks about over commenting and the problems that can cause, and I've experienced that. Now I try to make comments only when they are needed to explain things. It would be different I had a strict un-changing API with lots of external users. That's not my environment. YMMV.

Comment: @jordanthompson I've updated the answer with the possible field names and their usages. Hopefully this answers your question

Comment: that was a great, comprehensive explanation, and it does work in my pycharm version, but...  I would like to indicate what the parameters represent (i.e. returns "the number of cars on the freeway") like you can do with the parameters being passed into the function.

Comment: So you're saying you have `param a`, `param b` for input vals, and you have a tuple for return, you want to have a separate line in your doc for each return?

Comment: You can try putting in escape characters into the `:return: desc`, but this doesn't seem to work well with my version of PyCharm (older). If you're really wanting to be this rigid about return structures, you should probably be creating a return object, and then you can document the values in the object. I feel the answer provided answers the question asked.

Comment: Yes, of course you did answer my question. Thank you